# How To rounded to the lowest multiple of 5 in SQL SERVER 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

how to round a number to the minimum number that is a multiple of 5

Examples:

- if we have 49 it should be rounded to 45 not 50
- if we have 54 it should be rounded to 50.

This is wrong:

```
SELECT ROUND(49, -1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer arithmetic will do it

```
SELECT FLOOR(49/5) * 5,  FLOOR(54/5) * 5
```